# How can *$R$ be a field in Synthetic Differential Geometry or Smooth Infinitesimal analysis?

Tags: synthetic-differential-geometry

In many sources it was written that *$R$ is ring and *$R$ can't be a field because it's not possible that $d^2=0$ in field.

But in some sources it was written that *$R$ is a field.

How can *$R$ be a field in Synthetic Differential Geometry or Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis?

Thanks.

Comment: Which sources are you referring to?

Comment: @MarkSaving https://www.math.ru.nl/~landsman/scriptieTim.pdf (page 16) - ring. https://pages.physics.ua.edu/staff/fabi/InvitationSDG.pdf (page 3) - "Nevertheless most of the literature refers to R simply as a ring while a few authors still refer to R as a field"

Comment: Why do you use $^\ast \!R$ do denote the line of SDG?  Both sources you linked use simply $R$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz It's my mistake. *$R$ was in Giordano's source which I read.

Comment: @Mike_bb, Giordano is *not* doing Synthetic Differential Geometry.  Furthermore, Giordano did not use ${}^\ast\!R$ but rather ${}^\bullet\! R$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Ok. I find now in Giordano's source that IDG differ from SDG. It's true. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SDG uses intuitionistic logic, it is important to specify how exactly you define a field.  If you want the property that if $x\not=0$ then $x$ is invertible, then this still holds.  Nilsquare infinitesimals do not provide a counterexample to this, since they are not provably nonzero.